# How to get relations using pivot table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have 4 tables similar to this:

**items** (id)

**subcategories** (id | category_id)

**item_subcategory** (item_id | subcategory_id) --pivot table

**categories** (id)

---

The items and  subcategories are connected to the pivot table with many to many relationship. How can I get all the items under each categories? Below is an example.

- Category 1

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
- Category 2

  - Item 4
  - Item 5
- Category 3

  - Item 2
  - Item 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be 3 ways we could use from my perspective, I'll share all.

1. Linking Relations: You can link relations on top of other relations eg.

```php
Category::with(['subcategories' => function ($query) {
   $query->whereHas('items');
}])->get();
```

It will get all the subcategories first, then the related items something like that =>

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Category 1",
    "subcategories": [{
        "id": 1,
        "category_id": 1,
        "title": "Subcategory 1",
        "items": [{
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Item 1",
            "pivot": {
                "subcategory_id": 1,
                "item_id": 1
            }
        }]
    }]
}]
```

2. Add category id into a pivot table and make new relation eg:

```php
public function items()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, ItemSubcategory::class);
}
```

It will allow you to directly fetch products without loading subcategories first, something like that.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Category 1",
    "items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Item 1",
        "pivot": {
            "category_id": 1,
            "item_id": 1
        }
    }]
}]
```

3. Using **hasManyThrough**, you can create a relation by depending on other classes if your item table contains a subcategory id.

```php
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Item::class, ItemSubcategory::class, null, 'id', null, 'item_id');
    }
```

Comment: The first method is what I am currently using and it's working but I am wondering if there is a way to get the data like my example.

I also thought of the 2nd method but for some reason I don't want to add category id in the pivot table.

I am interested on the 3rd method but I don't know how to do this with the pivot table

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a sample for hasManyThrough, you can use the same pivot table and add a new column for category id or you can create a new separate table for category_item.

Comment: tried your 3rd option, it wasn't working on my end. End up creating an attribute (getItemsAttribute) on Category model to get all items by looping on each subcategories. but thanks for your help. those are great suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand completely but maybe this will be a solution for you, in your model

```
public function Categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'id', 'categoryID');
    }
```

Comment: i want to get all the categories and the items under each category. maybe with the help of the pivot table?